# Updating duplicate column values to append sort index from separate column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a `person` table with `name` and `popularity` columns. I am trying to figure out what SQL command I can run to update duplicate `name` values with an appended sort index of their relative `popularity` values. If possible, it would also be great if the duplicate `names` with top sort index `1` were left as-is and not updated. I've been noodling around with `ARRAY_AGG`, `GROUP BY`, `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`,`RANK () OVER`, and `PARTITION BY`, but lack the SQL expertise to wrangle these into a working solution. I suspect I am probably going about it completely wrong. Any help or direction would be hugely appreciated!

Example

```
id    name    popularity
0     jane    1.5
1     joe     0.5
2     jane    0.0
3     jane    0.0
4     joe     1.4
5     emily   0.5
```

Desired Results

```
id    name    popularity
0     jane    1.5
1     joe-2   0.5
2     jane-2  0.0
3     jane-3  0.0
4     joe     1.4
5     emily   0.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` to enumerate the duplicate names and then `join` to attach this information to each row:

```
update person p
    set name = name || '-' || seqnum
    from (select p.*,
                 row_number() over (partition by name order by popularity desc, id) as seqnum
          from person p
         ) pp
    where pp.id = p.id and seqnum > 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select
    *,
    row_number() over (partition by name order by popularity) as num,
    name || '-' || (row_number() over (partition by name order by popularity))::text as name_new
from person;
```

Use [`UPDATE ... FROM ...`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html)

Comment: This helped put me on the right track, but seemed to be missing some of the necessary logic from the answer @GordonLinoff provided. Thank you so much regardless, though! Bless up all ye sacred SO SQL wizards. 

Comment: @Ross Usually I trying to leave some quest to OP. You need to learn something by yourself at my answer. It is main difference from Gordon's answer IMO. Good luck anyway! :)